Joint convergence with constant transformed marginal
Consider random variables $X$ and $Y$ (not independent), and a sequence of random variables $X_n$ that converges to $X$.
Here, whenever I speak of convergence, I mean convergence in distribution.
Let $g$ be a measurable function.
In general, it is not the case that $(X_n,Y)$ converges to $(X,Y)$ or that $g(X_n)$ converges to $g(X)$.
However, I found myself in the special case in which I know that $(X_n,Y)$ converges to $(X,Y)$, and I am interested in whether $(X_n,g(Y))$ converges to $(X,g(Y))$.
This seems intuitive to me since $g(Y)$ does not depend on $n$ and since $(X_n,Y) \rightarrow (X,Y)$ contains more information than I need for $(X_n,g(Y)) \rightarrow (X,g(Y))$.
However, since $g$ is not continuous, I find myself unable to deduce it rigorously.
Maybe I am misled to think this is true?
tldr; Suppose $(X_n,Y) \rightarrow (X,Y)$ in distribution.
Does it follow that $(X_n,g(Y)) \rightarrow (X,g(Y))$ in distribution for a measurable $g$?

@geetha290krm If $g$ is continuous, then this is a consequence of the continuous mapping theorem.

There is a simple proof if you are willing to assume that $\mathbb E[|g(Y)|]<\infty$; the result will be true with more generality but maybe the proof is slightly more involved?
Since $g$ is in $L^1$, we can approximate with a continuous function $g_r$ such that $\mathbb E[|g_r(Y)-g(Y)|]\leq r$. Now it is not difficult to check that for convergence in distribution we only need to check Lipschitz functions. Take $\varphi$ to be continuous and $L-$Lipschitz, and quickly check
\begin{align*}
|\mathbb E[ \varphi (X_n,g(Y))-&\varphi (X,g(Y))]|\leq 
|\mathbb E[ \varphi (X_n,g(Y))-\varphi (X_n,g_r(Y))]|\\
&+|E[ \varphi (X_n,g_r(Y))-\varphi (X,g_r(Y))]|+  |E[ \varphi (X,g_r(Y))-\varphi (X,g_r(Y))]|\\
&\leq 2 L \mathbb E[|g_r(Y)-g(Y)|]+|E[ \varphi (X_n,g_r(Y))-\varphi (X,g_r(Y))]|\\
&\leq 2Lr + |E[ \varphi (X_n,g_r(Y))-\varphi (X,g_r(Y))]|  
\end{align*}
Now take r small enough and then n large enough.
You can most likely extend the above to a measurable $g$ that does not have a finite integral by truncating carefully.

Thank you for this helpful answer! I have no problem assuming that $g(Y)$ is integrable. Something I have neglected in my post (thinking it may not matter much depending on the proof strategy) was the underlying space. I am interested in random variables that take values in a Polish space, not necessarily $\mathbb{R}$. I would expect that continuous functions are still dense in the set of integrable functions, but I am unable to locate a proof of this.

Nevermind, I found density of $C_b$ in $L^1$ in Bogachev's Vol. 2.
